# Adding a pandas data frame column using taking abbreviated weekday and giving weekday number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column with weekday number to a data frame that currently has weekday listed as 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED' ...

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame(data={'ord_day': ['TUE', 'MON','TUE','WED','FRI']})
s


    ord_day
0   TUE
1   MON
2   TUE
3   WED
4   FRI
```

I tried using pandas.to_datetime with the format %w but it doesn't understand the input 'MON' etc

```
s['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(s['ord_day'],format ='%w')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward here would be to use a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
days = ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN']
mapper = {day: i for i, day in enumerate(days)}

s['weekday'] = s['ord_day'].map(mapper)
```

Or:

```
from calendar import day_abbr

mapper = {day.upper(): i for i, day in enumerate(day_abbr)}

s['weekday'] = s['ord_day'].map(mapper)
```

If you really want to use `to_datetime`, you need to cheat a bit and add enough information to build a datetime (a year and a week number), then only extract the day of week (IMO this is a waste of computing).

```
s['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime('1900-01 '+s['ord_day'],
                              format='%Y-%W %a').dt.day_of_week
```

Output:

```
  ord_day  weekday
0     TUE        1
1     MON        0
2     TUE        1
3     WED        2
4     FRI        4
```